# Sql Query regarding Join

Tags: sql

I have two tables as follows:

Table 1:

```
Name | Specialisation
```

Table2:

```
Name | Slot | Date
```

I take user input of Name, Slot and Date. I want to display the records of Table1 for that Name such that there exists no record corresponding to the entered (Name, Slot, Date) in Table 2. What will be the SQL query for it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing the input values were `input_name`, `input_slot`, and `input_data`, and the `input_date` was a suitable date format, one way to do it would be:

```
select name, specialisation from table1
where (name = input_name)
    and (select name from table2
         where (table2.name = input_name) and
               (table2.slot = input_slot) and
               (table2.date = input_date)) is NULL
```

Or something like that... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a not in

```
select name
from table1
where name not in (
select name from table2
)
```

or not exists

```
select name
from table1
where name not exists (
select name from table2
where table2.name = table1.name
)
```